# Return key by value when multiple values

Tags: ruby, hash

Here is a hash:

```
cities = {
  OR: ['Bend','Portland'],
  CA: ['Los Angeles', 'Sandiego'],
  WA: ['Seattle', 'Vancouver'],
}
```

I am looking to return a key by an element of a value. I would like to return the state's abbreviation (key) when I search by a city name (element in a value).

The following only works when `value` is a value of the hash, not when it is an element of a value:

```
hash.key(value)
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, there is only ever one value per key, but here that value is an array which itself has many values, which is why this doesn’t work: `Hash#key` doesn’t care that your value is a collection.

Comment: You have design flaw. The keys and the values should be the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the key by using `select`:

```
hash.select { |k, v| v.include? "Seattle" }.keys.first
```

Comment: Could use `detect` to eliminate the `keys` call—if it is true that a City will only be represented once.